# $P(x)=x^5+a_4x^4+\cdots+a_0$ has roots $1,2,3,4$ and $k$. Find $P(5) -P(0)$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, roots

A polynomial $P(x)$ with leading coefficient $1$ is of degree $5$, and its distinct roots are $1, 2, 3, 4$ and $k$. Find the value of $P(5) -P(0)$.

I have no clue on what my initial steps should be.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Using the information of the question we obtain that the polynomial $P$ has to be of the form:
$$
P(x)=(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-k),
$$
in which case
\begin{align}
P(5)-P(0) &= (5-1)(5-2)(5-3)(5-4)(5-k)-(0-1)(0-2)(0-3)(0-4)(0-k)\\ &=24(5-k-0+k)=120.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that $P(k)=0$ means "and for some $k\in \mathbb{R}$, we have $P(k)=0$": This means that $1,2,3,4,k$ are roots, or zeros of a polynomial of degree 5, which looks like this if you factorize it:
$$P(x)=c(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-4)(x-k),$$
for some $c \in\mathbb{R}$.*  Since the leading coefficient is 1, we conclude $c=1$. Thus, $P(5)=4*3*2*1*(5-k)$ and $P(0)=(-1)*(-2)*(-3)*(-4)*(-k)$, i.e. $$P(5)-P(0)=24*(5 - k + k)=120.$$

*Note: It's no loss of generality to assume $k \neq 1,2,3,4$.

Answer (score 0):

Exploit innate *symmetry.* Monic $P$ of degree $2n\!+\!1$ has roots $S=\{1,2,\ldots,2n\},\,$ root $k\not\in S$ so $P = (x\!-\!k)Q,\,
$ monic Q of degree $2n$ has $2n$ roots $S,\,$ same for $Q(2n\!+\!1\!-\!x)\,$ by $2n\!+\!1-S = S$. Thus $\,Q(2n\!+\!1\!-\!x)=Q(x)\,$ so $\,Q(2n\!+\!1)=Q(0),\,$ so $\,P(2n\!+\!1)-P(0) = (2n\!+\!1)Q(0) = (2n\!+\!1)!$

**Remark** $\ $  The *reflection symmetry* exploited above is essentially the same symmetry yielding the *reflection formula* for falling/lower factorial polynomials $\,x(x\!-\!1)\cdots (x\!-\!n\!-\!1).\,$ This is useful in many contexts where related objects arise (binomial coefficients, gamma functions, etc).